# How to dynamically pass the variable name into the model in the laravel provider's model config.php file

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, breeze

For instance let's say the

'''

```
    $model_name = 'student_table';
```

'''

```
'providers' => [

        'users' => [
                '$model_name' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\.$model_name.::class
                ]
        ]
]
```

The problem is that laravel fires an unexpected '.' expecting identified (T_STRING)

And I need to insert the model name dynamically because there lot of database tables to connect with. Any other solution pls

Answer (score 0):

That is a syntax error.
After `App\Models\` you can't have `.`, It expects you to write the class name next.

Try this:

```
'providers' => [

    'users' => [
            '$model_name => [
                  'driver'=> 'eloquent',
                   'model' => "App\Models\\" . $model_name
            ]
    ]
]
```

Notice you don't need `::class` anymore as you have the full namespace of the class in string.

Comment: The ** ::class** isn't part of the $model_name variable, how can I append that

Comment: @BalogunGbenga You don't need that!

Comment: I get an error saying Class 'App\Models\' not found

Comment: @BalogunGbenga That's probably because `$model_name` is empty

Comment: Yeah, I think that's it, is there a way to pass the variable to the config.php file when authenticatin please?

Comment: @BalogunGbenga You can set config https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Answer (score 0):

that's not going to work, providers are loaded way before the controller is.

maybe if you use a config table in database that orient users to own specific auth table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/lifecycle

Comment: I'm using laravel 8.0 pls

Comment: its same, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle, try with a configuration table associated with the user to know which table to call